# Сокращения имен

Tags: общие-вопросы

Это не совсем касается русского языка, но мне очень нужен совет.
Как вы думаете, имелись ли в древние времена "домашние" сокращения имен? В частности меня интересуют латинские и древнегреческие имена.

Answer (score 3):

Если брать древние эпохи, то почти у всех народов есть понятие о сакральности имени. Если человек знал настоящее имя человека, то он мог наложить на него наговор и прочее колдовство. Как пример, мы только можем предполагать произношение имени библейского Бога.

В итоге у всех было два имени - сакральное и мирское. Нетрудно догадаться, что имена Святополк, Ярополк, Мирослав и другие не могли быть настоящими именами русских князей, после принятия православия (их нет в "Святцах"). Почти наверняка подобное было и у греков с римлянами. Имён сакральных, мы за редким исключением не знаем, а вот "домашние имена" и зачастую прозвища до нас дошли.

Конкретно римская модель имени довольно интересна.  Римское имя состояло из 4 частей:
преномен — личное имя, которое мальчик получал на восьмой или девятый день после рождения,
номен — имя рода,
когномен — прозвище, дававшееся кому-либо из родственников, и которое в дальнейшем могло стать названием семьи, и
агномен — личное прозвище, дававшееся в результате каких-либо заслуг.
Так как преномен, номен и когномен передавались по наследству, то агномен часто становился необходимостью (первые четыре сына наследовали имя отца).
Например, Гай Юлий Цезарь Калигула: Гай — преномен (личное имя), Юлий — номен (т.е. из рода Юлиев), Цезарь — когномен (из семьи Цезарей), Калигула — агномен (личное прозвище).

Answer (score 0):

Где-то это вопрос уже разбирался... Пришли к выводу, что вряд ли. Но все дело в том, что "письменный" греческий и особенно латинский сильно отличались от разгноворного. Свидетельств об этом могло и не сохраниться...

Answer (score 0):

А мне кажется, что имелись. Ну не могу я представить компанию хулиганов-мальчишек, обращающихся друг к другу в драке полными длинными именами)))

Comment: Это вы о каком времени? Сомневаюсь я, что греческие мальчишки именно дрались. Да и римские - особенно в эпоху республики и ранней империи.
Их с детства до изнеможения учили обращатся с оружием... До драк ли тут? Но вообще вопрос, конечно, интересный... В литературе ничего похожего не встречал. Не знаю как с греками, у римлян для этого, кажется, использовалось первое имя - Гай (Юлий Цезарь). Хотя система именований у римлян весьма интересна, не похожя на современную.

Answer (score 0):

В  русской  мужской  компании  детского, подросткового  и  юношеского  возраста   люди  зовут  друг  друга  по  прозвищам  ( или  по  имени,  если  прозвище  не  прилипло ). Но  это  в  русской  среде  и  по  правилам  русского  языка.  У  других  народов  могло  быть  как-нибудь  не  так.  Например, в  современном  татарском  нет  ласкательной  именной  формы.